# Returning XML value in function

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, file-exists

I have a function that returns

```
if (file_exists($address)) {

    return simplexml_load_file($address) or die("Error loading XML");
}
else {

    return false;
}
```

Then on my pages I call my XML function

```
$page = fetchXML();

echo $page->title;
```

But I get

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in [...]
```

When I `var_dump($page);` I get `bool(true)`

Why isn't it returning my XML data?

---

**Note:**

If I

```
return $address
```

in my function, then use

```
$page = simplexml_load_file(fetchXML()) or die("Error loading XML");

echo $page->title;
```

it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you shouldn't shortcircuit it like that:

```
$ php -r'function foo(){ return 2 or false; } var_dump(foo());'
bool(true)
```

`return`  has *less* precedence then the `or` so to speak (actually, it's not an operator, so the whole expression is run), but `=` has a higher one.

```
$page = simplexml_load_file(fetchXML()) or die("Error loading XML");
```

Is the same as:

```
($page = simplexml_load_file(fetchXML())) || die("Error loading XML");
```

While

```
return simplexml_load_file($address) or die("Error loading XML");
```

Is the same as:

```
return (simplexml_load_file($address) or die("Error loading XML"));
```

See also [operator precedence](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @imoda: how do you mean? I'm not really clear on what you're asking there. `or` is a `||`, with the distinction it has a lower precedence then the assignment `=`.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I want the `or` to apply to the possible failure of `simplexml_load_file`, not the return value.  If I remove the `or die` my function works as intended.  However, I've tried using `||` and parenthesis, but I can't get it to work with the `or die` clause.  Can this be accomplished?

Comment: @imoda: just don't make a one-liner of it. Make it 2 distinct expressions, it increases legibility & makes the purpose clear.

Comment: Hm, 2 lines: `$page = simplexml_load_file(fetchXML()) or die("Error loading XML"); return $page;` Then again  `or die(` constructs should not be in production code. At the _least_ trigger some error that may get logged, but if you like your users, try a more graceful way of handling it. If not then & there, throw an Exception that is caught at the point where you _do_ know how to gracefully handle failures.